# install mcrypt for phpMyAdmin on Mac Lion with Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, phpmyadmin, osx-lion, mcrypt

I try to install phpMyAdmin on my Mac running Lion (10.7.3). It required mcrypt.

I found the link:

http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/08/29/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/

On my friend's Mac, the link is good. But on my Mac, it cannot run. I encounter the error from the statement of installing libmcrypt:

> ./configure

The command run as below:

```
sh-3.2# ./configure
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) no
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I see that my friend use Xcode 4.2, and I use Xcode 4.3. I'm not sure whether it's the reason. Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode, go to preferences and go to the 'Downloads' Tab, there you will find a list, find the one that says 'Command Line Tools' and click on Install and -> Done.

You would need an account as a developer to install that though, if you don't have one, create it, its free.